# Calling a function from outside functional component in react

Tags: reactjs, react-props, react-functional-component

Say I have a form outside a functional component like this:

```
   <TextField
        onChange={handleChange('name')}
        value={values.name}
        variant="outlined"
        label="Name"
        id="name"
        required
    />
```

And I have my component this way:

```
   export default function App() {
        const handleChange = (prop) => (event) => {
           setValues({ ...values, [prop]: event.target.value });
        };
   }
```

How do I call the `handleChange()` function from inside my component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass in the `handleChange` function as a prop to your functional component:

```
const MyComp = (props) => {
    ...
    return <TextField
        onChange={props.handleChange('name')}
        value={values.name}
        variant="outlined"
        label="Name"
        id="name"
        required
    />
}
```

```
// Reference function here.
<MyComp handleChange={handleChange}/>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you've a form component as a child component of a component, then you can do something like so:-

- `ParentComponent.js`:-

```
import ChildComponent from './ChildComponent

export default function ParentComponent() {
  const handleChange = (prop) => (event) => {
    setValues({ ...values, [prop]: event.target.value })
  }

  return (
    <ChildComponent 
      handleChange={handleChange} 
    />
  )
}
```

- `ChildComponent.js`:-

```
export default function ChildComponent({handleChange}) {
  return (
    <TextField
      onChange={handleChange('name')}
      value={values.name}
      variant="outlined"
      label="Name"
      id="name"
      required
    />
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, although I didn't wanna create another component, it helped.

Comment: It's okay. Glad you found what you need then.